# How to disable clicking on an accordion group heading?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/YOtT7O6ncaUMwKxmBZPd?p=preview) is a cut down version of the accordion example [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

```
  <accordion>
    <accordion-group heading="Static Header">
      This content is straight in the template.
    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
```

How is it possible to disable clicking on the accordion group heading. I tried **ng-disabled=true** on the accordion element and the accordion-group element but it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the source there is an isDisabled property on the accordeon group, which is used in the toggle function. This should be the way to disable a panel.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js

The toggle function:

```
scope.toggleOpen = function() {
 if ( !scope.isDisabled ) {
     scope.isOpen = !scope.isOpen;
 }
};
```

edit: this is not part of the 0.10 version you are using, so you have to get the main version, or make the change yourself.

Comment: I think you have to make a new file yourself, based on the js files in the master release. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/archive/master.zip The directives are supposed to be independend of each other so you could also try to use only the new version of the accordeon.

Comment: You propably have to remove the accordion from the 0.10 min file. Maybe creating a new minified file from the master branche is a better idea.

Comment: You can just remove the accordion part from the unminified 0.10 version, replace is with the new accordion and minify it yourself. I updated your plunker and it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/6pbQ4zW4zHRy6T3yg9We

Comment: One thing to note in Tim's edited bootstrap.js is the little tweek on line 3431 to make 'isDisabled' work with the new accordion directive.

Answer (score 5):

You need to get the latest ui-bootstrap libraries (No released version yet, need to get the Master) and use something like

```
<accordion-group is-disabled="true" heading="Static Header">
```

This is not even present in the 0.10.0 that you are using in your plnkr

Comment: Adding attribute `is-disabled="true"` solved my issue. Thanx